# Expo Permissions askAsync method does not return

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am using Expo Permissions API to request permissions for my iOS app. The following method does not return after showing the permissions dialog.

```
  async initializePushNotificationsIos(cb) {
    const permission = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS)
    Analytics.track({
      event: 'notification_permissions',
      status: permission.status === 'granted' ? 'granted' : 'denied',
    })
    cb()
    Notifications.registerRemoteNotifications()
    await this.updateUserDeviceToken()
  }
```

The code does not come back to the next step - Analytics.track call.

I am using Expo SDK 36 and corresponding React native version. Any reason why this is happening? This code was working at some point of time before and now does not work!